# How can I create a mirror material for the game engine?

Tags: materials, game-engine

A google search found this demo of a mirror in the BGE [Video:Mirror Made in Blender Game Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xXQ2ToolfE) but I can't find out how to setup the material. Unlike in the BI renderer the option *Mirror* isn't available when in BGE.

What tricks do I need to know?

Comment: It is called render to texture, you can also set it to mirror instead of UV, Generated, Object...etc. Here is a simple tutorial on render to texture inside of the blender game engine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPFhX_ogL2Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily fake it for *Multitexture* and *GLSL* - shading modes:

- Give the Object a material
- Give the material an image texture
- In the *Mapping* panel of that texture, set the Coordinates to *Reflection*

To make it work, you should use a sphere map and use camera view. I did this sphere map by setting the camera to orthographic (*Orthographic Scale* of 2.0, because the sphere is 2 blender units in diameter) and rendering a reflective sphere.

[image: Spheremap generated with Blender]

The result looks like this:

[image: Suzie with reflection map applied]

Answer (score 7):

It is possible by using [`bge.texture.ImageMirror`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_62_1/bge.texture.html).
Basically the mirror objects texture is frame by frame replaced with a video-texture which is captured by another camera.

[image]

A [**tutorial and an example**](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/VideoTexture/VideoTexture_Mirror_1.html) .blend file which works with Blender 2.68.

Comment: So is this always one frame behind?

Comment: @WChargin currently I don't understand the implications of the script included in the .blend file.

Comment: Image without anti-aliasing is a bit strange... But it does work for me when I download a 2.6 example blend and open with 2.7, but I can not make one in my game in 2.72. Who can help me?