# Live display of a camera output in the game engine?

Tags: materials, game-engine

What I'm trying to achieve is a TV type of display with a live feed from a camera in the game. How to display what the camera sees as a texture?

Comment: See my answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/how-can-i-create-a-mirror-material-for-the-game-engine there is a tutorial with sample .blend linked.

Comment: Use the render to texture script provided on the blenderartists forums or use this link, this one helped me a year ago. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPFhX_ogL2Y