# Real Time Reflections in the BGE

Tags: python, texturing, game-engine

I'm trying to achieve real time reflections in the game engine, possibly using the render to texture module if needed, but am not sure exactly how to go about it. Faking reflections using cube maps, etc, are simple enough, but that doesn't achieve a true reflection.
I want to be able to see a true reflection of my character if he/she moves in front of the mirror.

If you're still confused, take a look at a real mirror. That is what I want to simulate.
Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgSWZV4hvNo or the following
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JUYFGkmE1Y
Follow the link attached to the youtube video and you will find discussion on the matter there, I am afraid there are very few who write about or have alot to share on this topic, as blender BGE is very much in development for 2.8.

Comment: You will wanna watch post by this guy **martins upitis** on youtube and on blenderartist.org

Comment: @hawkenfox Thanks, this may be of some use to me. Martins Upitis is definitely a good artist to keep an eye on. Do you know if "bge.texture.ImageMirror" still works in the latest builds? I have never used it before, as I can only find older forums referring to it.

Comment: Unfortunately I havent have the time to dig too deep into the code. Mostly of what I do is to cut and paste and understand on the surface of what they do. BGE is getting alot of rebuilding this year, I am holding the horses until they announce a clearer picture of what the future BGE will be like in blender before learning things that will eventually get scraped.

Comment: I did read up a dev blog on the BGE development, it seems that they need a real major overhaul. It has become a real pain to develop BGE due to poor code housekeeping according to one of the dev. So will see what happens .... soon enough.

Comment: See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/how-can-i-create-a-mirror-material-for-the-game-engine

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks @stacker for reminding me of that link. Whenever I came upon that forum I always thought the Image Mirror was for older versions of blender, but apparently it still works in 2.74. Thanks for the redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorials for blender 3d has an excellent tutorial [over here](http://gametutorials.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Mirror/Page1)

It uses renderToTexture with a mirrored UV map and a camera facing out of the mirror.
One thing to keep in mind is that this requires the scene to be rendered twice: once from the main camera, once from the mirror camera. As such, it can increase processor load quite a lot.